# Different calculations between ST_Transform and CoordTransform that involves presition

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgis, geodjango

I am working with GeoDjango and Postgis, and doing transformation on a point from 4326 to 24877, when I have checked the result, it is not the same

**My values are:**

```
Latitude -16.42238172128686
Longitude -71.47541752550751
```

[image: Initial position]

**Using long lat as x, y coord**

```
In [63]: pnt = Point(-71.47541752550751, -16.42238172128686, srid=4326)
In [64]: pnt.transform(CoordTransform(SpatialReference(4326), SpatialReference(24877)))
In [65]: pnt.x, pnt.y, pnt.srid
Out[65]: (1521142.247877425, 8160547.8770980425, 24877)
```

**Inverse**

```
In [66]: pnt = Point( 1521142.247877425,8160547.8770980425, srid=24877 )
In [67]: pnt.transform(CoordTransform(SpatialReference(24877), SpatialReference(4326)))
In [68]: pnt.x, pnt.y, pnt.srid
Out[68]: (-71.47541753138003, -16.42238165040434, 4326)
```

[image: Position after calculus]

**SQL on Postgres**

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.47541752550751, -16.42238172128686), 4326),24877))

POINT(1520903.86571082 8160169.90886929)
```

**Taking data from postgis results**

```
In [69]: pgs = Point(1520903.86571082, 8160169.90886929, srid=24877)
In [70]: pgs.transform(CoordTransform(SpatialReference(24877), SpatialReference(4326)))
In [71]: pgs.x, pnt.y, pgs.srid
Out[71]: (-71.47745375612124, -16.42238165040434, 4326)
```

[image: Image on sql results]

As you could see there is a difference between geodjango and postgres, on at least 300 meters, and that means different places

After reading and asking on some forums and chats, I have found that this is related to presition, I was asking more about it on internet, as a newbie on this topic, this is getting some heard to fin.

I am looking for information that give me enough knowledge for continue working on it, for example:

1. The right way on do that
2. The reason on this difference
3. how many meters are the difference between systems or the right way on calculate that
4. how to validate this positions
5. what is the best way on work this information

Comment: The correct axis order is longitude/latitude, i.e: x=longitude, y=latitude. Furthermore, which SRID? `28477` or `24877`? What does `SELECT postgis_full_version()` return?

Comment: Thanks for teh answer, this was a type writing error, the srid that I am looking for is 24877

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/24877/ you can see that EPSG 24877 is only valid between -84.0000, -10.4000, -78.0000, 0.0000, and the point you're trying to transform is outside that (-71.475 isn't within -84,-78 and -16.422 isn't within -10.4,0)

A secondary issue might be if a transform from WGS84 to PSAD56. There's a grid shift involved there. Unless you have some data which is already in PSAD56 I'd suggest WGS 84 / UTM zone 19S (EPSG:32719) which has bounds of -72.0000, -80.0000, -66.0000, 0.0000.

If you absolutely need PSAD56 you might have more luck with PSAD56 / UTM zone 19S (EPSG:24879) but there still might be grid shift issues.

Answer (score 2):

csotelo: you have lat/long switched around, that point doesn't seem to exist in 24877

```
>>> p = Point(-16.42238172128686,-71.47541752550751, srid=4326)
>>> p.transform(24877)
>>> print p
POINT (2388367.8123248801566660 916017.4938517492264509)

# SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-16.42238172128686,-71.47541752550751), 4326),24877));
                st_astext                 
------------------------------------------
 POINT(2388367.81232488 916017.493851751)
```

Point(-71.47541752550751, -16.42238172128686, srid=4326) is outside the region defined by 24877 and therefore can only be approximated. You'll find that that point is actually near antarctica.
https://maps.google.nl/maps?q=-71.47541752550751,+-16.42238172128686&hl=en&ll=-71.475417,-16.422382&spn=60.209188,270.527344&sll=53.157645,5.636521&sspn=1.462449,4.22699&t=m&z=3

Comment: Sorry, I though you dont read my question well, cause you have switched points, my lat/long is -16.42238172128686, -71.47541752550751, srid=4326 and according projection docs, x is longitude and y is latitude, then when you work on proyections, you work with Point(-71.47541752550751, -16.42238172128686, srid=4326), and doing it on django and and postgis, make a diference, a litle difference, but I was looking for the reason of that, reading it, I have found that the reason is the axis used for the calculation, cause is just an aproximation not an exact point